# Date with Month name Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have an `NSDate` object with value for example: "2011-08-26 14:14:51", I want to display "8 August 2011" how to implement it? Thanks.

Comment: View all NSDateFormatters at https://nsdateformatter.com .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date]; //I'm using this just to show the this is how you convert a date

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle]; // day, Full month and year
[df setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];  // nothing

NSString *dateString = [df stringFromDate:date]; [df release];
```

Comment: this method does't work.. `[df setDateFormat:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];` - error and here - `[df setTimeFormate:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];`

Comment: @mazder - apologies - I've edited it this time. Try it again.

Comment: Thanks, now its ok.. But when I'm trying to get date from string it's displays `January 26, 2011` why?

Comment: Because the format given by Mayur Joshi is wrong. It should be @"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" because using D is for days of the year 1..365, not days of the month for which use dd

Answer (score 13):

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd LLLL yyyy"];
NSString *formattedDate = [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Answer (score 6):

```
NSString *dateStr = @"2011-08-26 14:14:51";

//if you have date then, 
NSString *dateStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",yourDate];



NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, YYYY"];
NSString* temp = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];

[dateFormat release];



NSLog(@"%@",temp);
```

Comment: Your date format string is wrong. it should be @"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss". D refers to days in a year d refers to days in the month